# Selecting the values of existing column as values of new columns with one row shift

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a question, I would be thankful if you help.

In the following picture I want to build a new column with the name: recent score
as you see the recent score is the score that a user gained last date. if we order rows by date, recent score is the score value of the below row.

[image]

I wrote the following code, but it's wrong :(

```
  SELECT [user-name],
         [submissions],
         [date],
         [score]

         (SELECT [score]
                 FROM [top-concept6] tc6
                 WHERE tc6.[user-name]=[top-concept6].[user-name]
                 AND tc6.[date]= (SELECT  TOP(1) [date] 
                 FROM [top-concept6] tcc6  
                 WHERE [date]<[top-concept6].[date] ORDER BY [date] DESC)) AS [recent-score]

   FROM [top-concept6]
```

this is sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74e3f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *, 
(select top 1 score from [top-concept6]
 where [user-name]=t1.[user-name]
       and [date]<t1.[date]
 order by date desc    
) recent_score
from [top-concept6] t1
```

[SQLFiddel demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44527/1)

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select 
    *,
    (select top 1 b.score from [top-concept6] b where b.[user-name]=a.[user-name] and b.date<a.date order by b.date desc) [Recent Score]
from 
    [top-concept6] a
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... your answer is correct too :)  I don't know how to thank you and stackoverflow members ...I always get very prompt answer